# Create Objects in a Loop and load them with XML informations

Tags: xml, loops, runtime

I spent a lot of time searching a solution to my problem but didn't find anything useful.
I want to load an ArrayList Object with an unknown number of Objects. The Objects are simple and contain string name, double number and bool check (myClass temp = new myClass(j, -7, false); for example).

The problem is a had to load those Objects with information's from my XML File.

I had some problems to copy the Code from my XML File so i wrote it without <> to show you how it looks.

XML Snippet:

```
root
  Information Name="test1" Time="7" Check="true"
  Information Name="test2" Time="-6" Check="false"
/root
```

C# Code Snippet:

```
public void readXmlFile()
        {
            XmlDocument newXML = new XmlDocument();
            newXML.Load(pathXML);
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

            int j = 0;
        ArrayList myArrList;
            foreach (XmlNode @daten in root.ChildNodes)
            {
                myClass temp = new TimeZone();
                myArrList[j].name = @daten.Attributes["Name"].InnerText;
                myArrList[j].number = @daten.Attributes["Number"].InnerText);
                myArrList[j].check = @daten.Attributes["Check"].InnerText);
            }
}
```

I hope someone can help me :)

I've got the solution by myself :)

```
public void readXmlFile()
{
    XmlDocument newXML = new XmlDocument();
    newXML.Load(pathXML);
    XmlElement root = newXML.DocumentElement;

    foreach (XmlNode @daten in root.LastChild.ChildNodes)
    {
        myClass temp = new TimeZone();
        temp.name = @daten.Attributes["Name"].InnerText;
        temp.number = Convert.ToDouble(@daten.Attributes["Number"].InnerText);
        temp.check = Convert.ToBoolean(@daten.Attributes["Check"].InnerText);
        myClassArrayList.Add(temp);
    }
}
```